# Hourly Recurring Job's Next Execution Time

Tags: hangfire

I have set up an hourly recurring job at the start of the Hangfire server. When I go to the dashboard I can see the job under the Recurring Jobs tab. However, the Next Execution says "in 6 hours" while the cron says "every hour."

Why is that?

Comment: Hm, strange. Can you paste a screenshot here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, attaching a comment here so I can add a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

For what it's worth, I just rebooted this box and when it came back up, it had the wrong time. IIS was running, and then I changed the clock.